# CNN in pytorch "Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [32, 1, 5, 5], but got 3-dimensional input of size [16, 64, 64] instead"

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am new to pytorch. I am trying to use chinese mnist dataset to train the neural network that shows in below code. Is that a problem of the neural network input or something else goes wrong in my code. I have tried many ways to fix it but instead it shows me other errors

```
train_df = chin_mnist_df.groupby('value').apply(lambda x: x.sample(700, random_state=SEED)).reset_index(drop=True)
x_train, y_train  = train_df.iloc[:, :-2], train_df.iloc[:, -2]

valid_df = chin_mnist_df.groupby('value').apply(lambda x: x.sample(200, random_state=SEED)).reset_index(drop=True)
x_valid, y_valid  = valid_df.iloc[:, :-2], valid_df.iloc[:, -2]

test_df  = chin_mnist_df.groupby('value').apply(lambda x: x.sample(100, random_state=SEED)).reset_index(drop=True)
x_test, y_test    = test_df.iloc[:, :-2], test_df.iloc[:, -2]


train_ds = Dataset(x_train, y_train)
train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size=16, shuffle=True)

valid_ds = Dataset(x_valid, y_valid)
valid_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(valid_ds, batch_size=16, shuffle=True)

test_ds = Dataset(x_test, y_test)
test_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_ds, batch_size=16, shuffle=True)


# Convolutional neural network (two convolutional layers)
class ConvNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConvNet, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
        self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
        self.drop_out = nn.Dropout()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(7 * 7 * 64, 1000)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1000, 15)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.layer1(x)
        out = self.layer2(out)
        out = out.reshape(out.size(0), -1)
        out = self.drop_out(out)
        out = self.fc1(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        return out

model = ConvNet()
klisi=[]
apoklisi=[]
apoklisi2=[]
klisi2=[]
olatalr=[]
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
total_step = len(train_dataloader)
loss_list = []
acc_list = []
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i,data in enumerate(train_dataloader):#(images, labels) 
        batch_inputs, batch_labels = data[0][:].to(device).type(torch.float), data[1][:].to(device)
        # Run the forward pass
        outputs = model(batch_inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, batch_labels)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your training images are greyscale images. That is, they only have one channel (as opposed to the three RGB color channels in color images).
It seems like your `Dataset` (implicitly) ["squeezes"](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.squeeze.html#torch.squeeze) this singleton dimension, and instead of having a batch of shape `B`x`C`x`H`x`W` = `16x1x64x64`, you end up with a batch of shape `16x64x64`.
Try:

```py
# ...
batch_inputs, batch_labels = data[0][:].to(device).type(torch.float), data[1][:].to(device)
batch_inputs = batch_inputs[:, None, ...]  # explicitly add the singleton channel dimension
# Run the forward pass
# ...
```