# Create a CNN that has a Kernel that is 1xD, where D is number of columns that slides vertically over a MxD matrix?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

Create a CNN that has a Kernel that is 1xD, where D is number of columns that slides vertically over a MxD matrix?

I'm trying to create a CNN in Pytorch that has a kernel that slides a 1xD kernel over a 2D image vertically so the output should be Mx1. As in the CNN convolves each row of the image then produces a single value for each row. Also having the ability to change from a 1xD to a NxD where N is some predefined number of rows would be nice as well. The input is purely just a matrix not a 3D matrix representing an image.

Answer (score 1):

Kernels in [`nn.Conv2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.9.0/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html#torch.nn.Conv2d) do not have to be square, they can also be rectangular:

```py
class MyModel(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, N, D):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=(N, D), padding=0, stride=1)

  def forward(self, x):
    return self.conv(x)
```

Note that your input `x` has to be 4 dimensional: `B`-`C`-`H`-`W`. Where the number of channels `C` must match `in_channels` defined when constructing `MyModel`.
If you have a single image with only one channel, then the input should have two leading singleton dimensions: that is, `x` should have the shape `1`-`1`-`M`-`D`.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66969439/1714410) answer for more information about why `x` should be 4D.

Comment: thanks for your input I decided to just do a 1d conv since it automatically slides across feature number for how many you want